# Validating a HTML error

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to solve a `HTML` error but do not know how. The error is:

> "Element 'a' not allowed as child element in this context."

The source code is:

```
<div class="navigation-previous-blog bd_headings_text_shadow zero_color fade_anchor"> 
<a href="http://www.acessibilidadeweb.pt/?pirenko_team_member=frederico-branco" alt="Frederico Branco" rel="next" data-pir_title="Frederico Branco"> <div class="icon-left-bold"></div>
```

And the php code is:

```
<div class="navigation-previous-blog bd_headings_text_shadow zero_color fade_anchor"> 
    <?php 
        next_post_link_plus( array(
            'in_same_cat' => true,
            'format' => '%link',
            'link' => ' <div class="icon-left-bold"></div><div class="after_icon_blog"><h5 class="header_font">%title</h5></div>'
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to close the "a" tag <a ..>sometext?</a>. And also you should close the first opened div

Comment: This appears to be for WordPress. You may want to add that tag. Did you review http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress ? I suspect you want to make use of `format` here.

Comment: `<a>` is inline, `<div>` is block. You can't have the latter inside the former.

Comment: No No No No No that's not how this works. Credit Twisty for solving your problem by clicking the check mark by his answer, then ask a new question. Don't just keep asking questions in the same thread and not credit anyone..

Comment: Ok @Adelphia sorry, i check mark his answer and i make a new question. Sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might have it backward. Try the following:

```
<div class="navigation-previous-blog bd_headings_text_shadow zero_color fade_anchor"> 
    <?php 
        next_post_link_plus( array(
            'in_same_cat' => true,
            'format' => ' <div class="icon-left-bold"></div><div class="after_icon_blog"><h5 class="header_font">%link</h5></div>',
            'link' => '%title'
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

Per http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress, they give the following example:

```
<?php
next_post_link_plus( array(
    'link' => '%title',
    'format' => '%link (posted in %category on %date by %author)'
) );
?>
```